# Sampling values at coordinates

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have a list of coordinates in some format, e.g.:

```
my_lats = [12.233, -21.123, 85.112]
my_lons = [-12.543, -51.231, 5.562]
```

The list is actually about 10 000 locations.

I also have a xarray data set with coordinates. It is e.g. 3600x1800 large:

```
data = xr.open_dataarray('my_global_data.nc')
```

How do I best extract the interpolated values at each coordinate in my list?

I can do this:

```
for my_lat, my_lon in zip(my_lats, my_lons):
    data_value = data.interp({'LAT': my_lat, 'LON':my_lon})
```

However, using iteration is slow.

I can give a list or array, however, this generates a new 2D grid.

```
data_value = data.interp({'LAT': my_lats, 'LON':my_lons})
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `xarray`, but otherwise, I'd just be telling you to be sure to use vectorization.. [`scipy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html) has what seems to be a very similar function with an example of how to use it.

Comment: Thanks, @Aaron. Good advice. I was hoping that xarray had a more direct method. There are plenty of good ways to generate regular grids, however, I did not find any good way to do the reverse, so far.